# DSolve returns wrong result

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, nonlinear

I tried to solve a nonlinear, partial differential equation for the function `Y[h, x]` by using the following code:

```
DSolve[2 h^3 x D[Y[h,x],x,x] + D[Y[h,x],x]^2 * D[Y[h,x],h] == 0, Y[h,x],{h,x}]
```

Mathematica gave the symbolic result:

```
Y[h, x] -> Exp[-h^4 x/2]  C[1][x] + C[2][h] + x C[3][h]
```

This does not seem to be a general solution for this equation, so I do not understand what is going on.

Comment: "I cannot understand why." - the `C[k][x]` and `C[k][h]` are arbitrary *functions*, which means you could replace any of the three with some function and the PDE would be satisfied.

Comment: Likely a bug in view of `FullSimplify[
 2*h^3 *x* D[Y[h, x], x, x] + 
   D[Y[h, x], x]^2*D[Y[h, x], h] /. {Y[h, x] -> 
    E^(-((h^4 x)/2)) C[1][x] + C[2][h] + x C[3][h], 
   D[Y[h, x], x] -> 
    D[E^(-((h^4 x)/2)) C[1][x] + C[2][h] + x C[3][h], x], 
   D[Y[h, x], {x, 2}] -> 
    D[E^(-((h^4 x)/2)) C[1][x] + C[2][h] + x C[3][h], {x, 2}], 
   D[Y[h, x], h] -> 
    D[E^(-((h^4 x)/2)) C[1][x] + C[2][h] + x C[3][h], h]}]` which produces

Comment: ``(C[3][h] - 
    1/2 E^(-((h^4 x)/
      2)) (h^4 C[1][x] - 2 Derivative[1][C[1]][x]))^2 (-2 E^(-((
      h^4 x)/2)) h^3 x C[1][x] + Derivative[1][C[2]][h] + 
    x Derivative[1][C[3]][h]) + 
 1/2 E^(-((h^4 x)/2))
   h^3 x (h^8 C[1][x] - 4 h^4 Derivative[1][C[1]][x] + 
    4 (C[1]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x])``,but not zero. Maple produces a quite different result.

Comment: @user64494 I agree that this is a bug.  What result does Maple produce?

Comment: @bbgodfrey: `pdsolve(2*h^3*x*diff(Y(h, x), x $ 2) + diff(Y(h, x), x)^2*diff(Y(h, x), h) = 0)` performs $${\it PDESolStruc} \left( Y \left( h,x \right) ={\it \_F1} \left( h
 \right) {\it \_F2} \left( x \right) ,[ \left\{ {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}
h}}{\it \_F1} \left( h \right) ={\frac {{\it \_c}_{{1}}{h}^{3}}{{\it 
\_F1} \left( h \right) }},{\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{x}^{2}}}{\it 
\_F2} \left( x \right) =-{\frac { \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}{
\it \_F2} \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}{\it \_c}_{{1}}{\it \_F2}
 \left( x \right) }{2\,x}} \right\} ] \right) 
 .$$

Comment: @bbgodfrey: Adding the `explicit` option, one obtains a detailed expression (too long to be cited here)..

Comment: It's a solution for `{C[1] :> (0 &), C[2] :> (c[2] &), C[3] :> (c[3] &)}` (`c[2]` and `c[3]` arbitrary constants), but probably for no other functions. At least there's some connection with the PDE. I agree it's probably a bug and should be reported to WRI.

Comment: @user64494  I did not expect the PDE to be separable, but it is.  `(2 h^3 x D[Y[h, x], x, x] + D[Y[h, x], x]^2*D[Y[h, x], h] /. Y -> Function[{h, x}, y1[h] y2[x]]); sep = Simplify[(Subtract @@ Solve[% == 0, y1'[h]][[1, 1]]) y1[h]/h^3]` does the separation.  Also, `DSolve` evaluates `y1` without difficulty, although it cannot handle `y2`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try with your seration of variables. The suggested by mathematica solution is not a solution, neither of separation of variables.

Comment: @user2966584  Please let me know, if you succeed.  I continue to think about this problem myself.

Comment: @user64494 Could you send me a pdf of the Maple solution?  Thanks.